# How to load a ribbon xml as a resource?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I made a ribbon resource at run time, and saved it to a destination. Now when I am trying to load it as a resource, I am unable to do so. Do anyone has any idea how to load a ribbon resource that is created at the run time and is saved to xml?
P.S. .xml file is saved successfully at the required destination.
 `this->SaveToXMLFile(strFilePathOfXml);`

Comment: There's an undocumented `CMFCRibbonBar::LoadFromBuffer` member, that takes an `LPCTSTR` pointing to the XML string. You can load your XML file into a buffer using [CFile::Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctka0kks.aspx). Since the XML file is encoded using UTF-8 you may have to convert it to UTF-16 before passing it off to `LoadFromBuffer`. Likewise, a UTF-16LE BOM and XML encoding tag may also be required.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution.Since it is not a native type resource, we have to declare it manually in .rc file, also define in resource.h
Visit the link under to get the clear picture.

[msdn link to convert and load xml resource as ribbon](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/converting-an-mfc-ribbon-to-designer-format/)